# "Adventurous" in a sentence

Tags: meaning

Trying to find the meaning of the [adventurous](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/adventurous) in the dictionary, I came across the sentence I couldn't understand:

> She wanted to get away from here, and she wasn't very adventurous.

The sentence is from the examples from the dictionary I referred to. So, almost all in the sentence is pretty clear except the meaning of `adventurous`.

Was that the reason for wanting to get away that she was not very adventurous? Can I say that adveturous here is something similar to showing enthusiasm of being there where she was?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of someone who has been growing up in small town. Let's say she doesn't like the small town, and would rather move someplace else. However, moving someplace else requires a lot of risk: you need to find a new job, you need to find a new place to live, you need to make new friends. All of this is part of the *adventure* moving.

So, if a person is "not very adventurous" – that is, if the person is (according to NOAD) not "willing to take risks or to try out experiences," that person's aversion to adventure might keep them from moving away for a very long time.

So, you asked:

> Was that the reason for wanting to get away – that she was not very adventurous?

The way I read the sentence, I took it to mean that that was her reason for staying. But more context might get me to change my interpretation.

Also, I would probably use *but* as the conjunction, not *and*:

> She wanted to get away from here, but she wasn't very adventurous.

However, the sentence was taken from a book by Ruth Brandon, and I'm not sure about the surrounding context. It could be a quote from a character, and the conjuction *and* might make more sense.

Answer (score 3):

Adventurous means daring, it involves liking thrills and possibly danger. 
The sentence you provided doesn't really provide the context to provide meaning.